# Delphi MSScriptControl JS Can't get a character from string by index

Tags: javascript, string, delphi, activex, scriptcontrol

I need to execute a JS script in a Delphi program.

There is a problem that bothers me.

I put `js: OleVariant;` into Form1's `public` section, and then use this code:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  js := CreateOleObject('ScriptControl');
  js.Language := 'JScript';
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Memo4.Text := js.Eval(Memo3.Text);
end;
```

After that, this JS code works normal:

```
var s = 'rtfm'
s.slice(0,1)
```

it returns `r`.

[image: Photo 1]

But this code:

```
var s = 'rtfm'
s[0]
```

returns emptiness.

[image: Photo 2]

And also this check;

```
var s = 'rtfm'
s[0]==undefined
```

returns true.

[image: Photo 3]

A similar situation is observed with the absence of a JSON object, so I could not execute `JSON.parse`. But I found [this code](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/json3/3.3.2/json3.min.js), and this again allowed me to use JSON after its execution.

Comment: @whosrdaddy I see, it does not work in IE7. Maybe msscript.ocx could be updated and start provide functions of IE8+?

Comment: IE7 is long obsolete now? Anyway Substring() should be supported in Internet Exploder...

Comment: @whosrdaddy I won't use my script in browser. It is only for some calculative goals. But script is very big, and it is too dreary to change it for IE7

Comment: Honestly, I don't see the relation with IE7, your question is about msscript.ocx??

Comment: @whosrdaddy you're right, I meant IE7 functionality

Comment: Sorry you lost me with your "it does not work in IE7" statement. Anyway your question has been answered by the dupe...